# if cv2.waitKey(1) with 2 cases

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
```

to quit the program, but I want to divide the kind of input in two cases like: if you press "q" you quit, else, if you press "d" do something.
I've tried to use elif but isn't working because the program still wait "q".

---

Another question is: if I want to use a timeout in case of you don't press any button using anyway cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'), how can I do that?

pseudo code*

```
if timeout:
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break
else:
   print("no interaction")
   do something
```

There's any kind of variable (timeout) that can do that?

thanks for help.

Comment: where in your code you have the `elif` that checks if "d" have been pressed? you are only checking for "q".

Comment: the documentation of `waitkey` tells you that the number you pass is the amount of milliseconds you wait for the key to be pressed. if you pass 0 it will wait infinitely until a key is pressed. so just use this parameter as a timeout.  https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This waits for a key to be pressed and stores it in `key` and you can use the key code in your conditions, if no key is pressed in 1000ms (k will be -1) it will quit.

```
k = cv2.waitKey(1000)
if k == -1:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
elif k == ord('a'):
    print("a key")


cv2.waitKey(0)
```